# While loop for float validation

Tags: python, regex, while-loop

I’m making a simple payment system  and I want to validate the purchase amount the user inputs. So far all I’ve managed to do is prevent the user inputting 0 or 0.00:

‘’’

```
amount = float(input(“amount of payment: “))
While amount <= 0:
  Print(“invalid input”)
  amount = float(input(“amount of payment: “))
else:
Runs the rest of the system
```

What would be the best way to prevent the user inputting any letters or characters such as - or £ and pretty much only allow whole number or decimal places numbers. I have briefly tried to use regex but I can’t get it to work

Comment: You can take advantage of `try-except`

Comment: What numbers are allowed? All positive, with how many decimal places?

Comment: All positive with any amount of decimal places, I have code further down to turn the number into 2 d.p